# How to link GitHub repository with JIRA project?

Tags: github, jira

I have a software project in JIRA and want to link that project with a GitHub repository so that when I create tasks in the JIRA project I can branch out in the corresponding GitHub repository, etc.  I was able to link my GitHub account with my JIRA account (https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/connect-jira-cloud-to-github-814188429.html) but I don't know how to connect one of my JIRA projects with a specific GitHub repository.

For example, when I create a task in my JIRA project I expect to see a link on the task page to create a branch.  There's no such links because the project is not linked to a repository.

EDIT: I don't see the Development panel on the issue page in JIRA.  If I were able to see that panel that would solve this problem (likely).

EDIT: I am trying to see this panel on the issue page.  This is from JIRA's help pages.  [image]

EDIT: Instead I see this (notice no Development panel on the right side that allows me to create a branch)  [image]

Comment: Any joy? I'm starting to think the integration is intentionally stunted to promote BitBucket, based solely on the difficulty of finding this information.

Comment: Me too -- GitHub has also now ZenHub so it seems to me their (GitHub and JIRA) honeymoon has ended.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1. Create an OAuth access token for your GitHub account**

1. Log in to GitHub as a user with admin permissions on the account.
2. Choose Edit Your Profile.
3. Select OAuth Applications.
4. Select the Developer Applications tab.
5. Choose Register new OAuth application.
6. Enter a name for Application Name.
7. Enter the JIRA Software URL for both the URL and Callback URL fields. Press Register Application.
8. Keep your browser open at your GitHub account while you go on with the next step.

**Step 2. Add the OAuth token in JIRA Software**

1. Log in to JIRA Software as a user with admin permissions.
2. From the JIRA Software dashboard click the cog (settings) icon.
3. Choose Applications.
4. From the Integrations section on the left, choose DVCS accounts.
5. Click Link Bitbucket Cloud or GitHub account.
6. Choose 'GitHub' as the Host value.
7. Enter a Team or User Account name.
8. Copy the Client ID and Client Secret values from your GitHub site into the dialog.
9. Leave the default auto link and Smart Commits (recommended) as is or change them
10. Click Add.
11. Grant access when prompted
12. When JIRA connects successfully, you'll see your account on the 'DVCS accounts' page.

Comment: I've already done this ... I don't see a dev  panel on the issue page that allows me to create a branch, etc

Comment: If you get redirected to a blank page at this point, see DVCS connection to GitHub produces blank page: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/dvcs-connection-to-github-produces-blank-page-779160707.html

Comment: What software are you using to access it?

Comment: I'm using JIRA in Google Chrome

Comment: Is only a GitHub Enterprise account allowed for integration?